# Jquery active link and ignore hashtag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery function for active page on menu.

```
var runUrlMatchActive = function() {
        var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
        $s(".v-nav .nav li a").each(function() {
            if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                $s(".v-nav .nav li").removeClass("active");
                $s(".v-nav .nav li").removeClass("deschis");
                $s(this).parent().addClass("active");
                $s(this).parent().parent().css({'display': 'block'});
                $s(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('deschis');
            }
        });
}
```

This is working great until i add a hashtag '#' at the end of the url.
How can i ignore the hastag ?

Comment: Can you add more information as to why you would need to ignore the hash in a url? Thats how links were designed to work, and simply cutting out a portion of a url you don't like doesn't seem like the right solution in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = location.href.toLowerCase().split('#')[0];
```